# how do you rerun validation on a text box after user makes a change

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

i have a text box that's required.  when user clicks the submit button, the validation fires and prevents the form from submitting if there's no value entered.  I want the error message to go away after the user types a value in the text box so that the user knows the value entered is valid.  Right now, the validation error message stays visible after the user makes a change.  I'm using jquery-validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function () {
    if (this.value === '') {
        //this input is blank
    }
});
```

You can set a flag for a `submit` event handler to check:

```
var error = false;
$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function () {
    if (this.value === '') {
        error = true;
        $(this).addClass('form-error');
    } else {
        error = false;
        $(this).removeClass('form-error');
    }
});
$('form').on('submit', function () {

    //trigger a `keyup` event on all the inputs in this form, to force validation if the input has not been changed
    $(this).find('input').trigger('keyup');
    console.log(!error);
    return !error;//will return true if there is not error, and false if there is an error
});​
```

Notice I used the `keyup` event since the `value` of the element will have changed by that point.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/NawBk/

Note that `.on()` is new as of jQuery 1.7 and is the same in this case as `.bind()`: http://api.jquery.com/on

And yeah, I just realized you're using the jQuery Validate plugin, I'll go ahead and leave this post because I think it can still help people.

Comment: I like this approach and can get it to work in my code.  I'm also using jQuery validation messages.  So, when user doesn't enter a value in a required field, a message is displayed in UI.  How do you get the message to disappear after the user types a value in the text box?

Comment: @TomSchreck In my code above, every-time a key is pressed in a text input, it gets validated, so if it's value is valid the error message should be removed when that validation is done. I also trigger a `keyup` event on every input to make sure it's been validated before sending the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form :input').on('keypress',function(){
  $(this).closest('form').validate();
});
```

Force it to re-validate as they're typing something. Though as soon as the user enters something, it should auto-recognize if it's valid or not. Make sure your validator is working as intended.